# phpmyadmin token mismatch error when using page drop-down for results

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've searched all the stackoverflow results for "phpmyadmin token mismatch" and tried all the solutions listed -- set the session.save_path in php.ini, checked permissions, reloaded the page, emptied cache, cleared cookies, made sure there's disk space, etc. etc -- but nothing has fixed the problem I'm having.

I'm only seeing the "token mismatch" error when I'm browsing a table, and use the "page number" select menu to jump to a different page. It gives me a token mismatch error every time. But everything else in phpmyadmin works fine. This is the latest version, 4.7.0.

Anyone have an idea what else I can check to get this working? For a large table, that page select menu is kind of necessary.

Comment: I also have the "token mismatch" in 4.7.0 but only after executing a large query... still looking for a solution...

Comment: Ok, in my case this looks like a reported issue (https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13206) I found a workaround: increase the LinkLengthLimit (ie $cfg['LinkLengthLimit'] = 10000;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug with phpMyAdmin described there:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13243

It should be fixed with phpMyAdmin 4.7.1.

If you have access to the phpMyAdmin code on your server, you could apply that fix: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/5ee4320b7de345062ced7e02aca65417baa8a944

Comment: Thanks, I applied the patch and that fixed it.